# how to write codeigniter query code for keyword search

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have written a method and model for keyword search. But I unfortunately I am getting the output which are matched with my keyword and also which does not have any match with the keyword I typed.

eg. if i typed keyword like "grisham" as author last name then i am getting the all other data(`book_title,auth_firstname,isbn`) as output including "grisham"(i.e `auth_lastname`)

*But the keyword i typed is only matching with the author_lastname. Then   Why other are display?* **only aUth_last name should display?**

Please help me ,to solve my problem.

controller.php

```
       function suggestions()
{
        $this->load->model('Booksmodel');
        $term = $this->input->post('term',TRUE); 
        $rows = $this->Booksmodel->GetAutocomplete(array('keyword' => $term)); 
        $json_array = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        array_push($json_array, $row->book_title);
        array_push($json_array, $row->auth_firstname);
        array_push($json_array, $row->isbn);
        array_push($json_array, $row->auth_lastname);
        array_push($json_array, $row->publisher_name); 

        echo json_encode($json_array);
}
```

model.php

```
 function GetAutocomplete($options = array())
  { 
    $this->load->database();   
    $this->db->limit('10');  
    $this->db->select('book_title,auth_firstname,isbn,auth_lastname,publisher_name');    
    $this->db->like('book_title', $options['keyword']);
    $this->db->or_like('auth_firstname', $options['keyword']); 
    $this->db->or_like('isbn', $options['keyword']);
    $this->db->or_like('auth_lastname', $options['keyword']);
    $this->db->or_like('publisher_name', $options['keyword']); 

    $query = $this->db->get('bookdetails');
      return $query->result();
    }
```